# What are the requirements for changes to a MutableState to properly trigger recomposition?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

I have my own observable properties library, inspired by JavaFX. In it, I define a class called BindableProperty. It essentially has all the same features and similar implementation details as JavaFX's `Property`.

Now I am beginning to really get into Compose. But unlike JavaFX where all of the low-level mechanics can be read directly in the source code of the library, Compose seems to have magic involved at the compiler level and code generation. This really complicates the process of developing custom low level implementations of interfaces like MutableState because I do not know what Compose expects me to do in that implementation.

My goal: I would like to retain the useful features I have developed in my observables library but also allow my observables to be observed by Compose to trigger Recompositions.

So, here is a rough example for what I am trying to achieve at baseline:

```kotlin
class BindablePropertyState<T>(initialValue: T) : MutableState<T> {

    val property = BindableProperty(initialValue)

    override var value: T
        get() = property.value
        set(value) {
            property.value = value
        }

    override fun component1(): T {
        return value
    }

    override fun component2(): (T) -> Unit {
        return {
            property.value = it
        }
    }

}
```

Conceptually, this does the following:

1. Creates a MutableState object to be used in Compose
2. Delegates reads and writes to another object.
3. Exposes this other object (`property` is public) so that it can be used for other purposes.

As a consequence of point 3, the internal value of `value` might change.

With this implementation alone, it is hard to imagine how Compose could possibly observe all changes to the object, unless it was constantly **polling**. However, I am pretty sure that Compose does not observe via polling.

The most frustrating thing about this is that there is not explicit code here to indicate where compose would register changes. For example, does it register changes only through the lambda returned from `component2`, or does it register from the setter of `value` as well?

Let me dive a bit deeper with a more barebones example:

```kotlin
class SimpleState<T>(initialValue: T) : MutableState<T> {

    override var value = initialValue

    override fun component1(): T {
        return value
    }

    override fun component2(): (T) -> Unit {
        return {
            value = it
        }
    }

}
```

What exactly in this case would trigger recomposition and what would not?

- Would setting through `component2` trigger recompositon?
- Would setting through the setter of `value` trigger recompositon?
- Would setting the value of `value` through refelction, either through kotlin or java reflection trigger recompositon?
- Can I set the value of `value` from any thread or coroutine? Is it guaranteed to trigger recompositon in any case?

Additionally, it would help to understand what this `SimpleState` implentation is lacking compared to default implentations. If you look at the source code behind the implementation of the class returned by `mutableStateOf()`, it clearly has many more features in addition to the barebones implementation of `MutableState` I wrote above. So what exactly are the consequences of losing these advanced features of the default `MutableState` implementation?

I also should note that I am primarily developing for Compose Multiplatform for Desktop currently. I am interested in how Compose works on any/all platforms, but just to be clear about the scope of my question.

For Desktop, `mutableStateOf` delegates to `createSnapshotMutableState` which creates an instance of `SnapshotMutableStateImpl`.

Looking briefly at the source code of `SnapshotMutableStateImpl`, we classes used such as:

- `SnapshotMutationPolicy`
- `StateObject`
- `SnapshotMutableState`
- `StateRecord`
- `StateStateRecord`

So, when comparing the default implementation of `MutableState` (`SnapshotMutableStateImpl`) to my barebones `SimpleState`, what are the differences, both practically and on a low level? Is `SnapshotMutableStateImpl` essentially just more optimized, or are there other features unrelated to performance and optimization that `SimpleState` is missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I asked this question, I was lost.

Then, finally I found a [blog post](https://dev.to/zachklipp/introduction-to-the-compose-snapshot-system-19cn) by Zach Kilppenstein that started to clarify everything for me. It is worth the read.

Let's return to a statement I made in in my original question.

> Compose seems to have magic involved at the compiler level and code generation

While this statement taken at face value is true, **the implication is false**. That is, the implication the compiler magic is used to register and listen to observable states.

At the bottom of his post, Zach corrected me on my most fundamental misunderstanding: **Compose does not set up state observations with compiler magic.** Compiler magic is used for other things, but the observation system is fully transparent in the source dependencies. It is based on the Snapshot system, which his post gives an introduction to.

After reading his post, I finally knew what I was really looking for. I dove into the source code of `SnapshotMutableStateImpl`, and made sure to fully understand it. The source code didn't reveal anything conceptually new; Zach's post covered all the essential concepts. But reading the source is helpful if looking at concrete implementation details help you wrap your head around a topic.

Also, to address another comment I made:

> unless it was constantly **polling**

No, Compose is not polling. It follows the typical observation pattern of registering change listeners, although with more layers of complexity.

Now, let's begin to answer my questions.

Will my `BindablePropertyState` or `SimpleState` above trigger recompositions? **No.**

`MutableState` is an interface, and offers the typical contract that an interface offers, which is that it tells you what something does but not how it does it. My implementations above simply do not in any way register listeners for observations. I was confused because of my fundamentally wrong assumption: I thought `MutableState` was acting more like an annotation and causing the compiler to generate code. This is not the case. The concrete implementations provided within the Compose library use the Snapshot system to register listeners for observation.

- Would setting through component2 trigger recompositon? **No.**
- Would setting through the setter of value trigger recompositon?
  **No.**
- Would setting the value of value through refelction, either through kotlin or java reflection trigger recompositon? **No.**

> Can I set the value of value from any thread or coroutine? Is it guaranteed to trigger recompositon in any case?

My implementations above will never trigger recomposition.

However, it is worth noting that it is safe to update a `MutableState` (a correctly implemented one) from any thread, at any time. In normal cases it has no reason to cause any error, and will always trigger recomposition. That is part of the design of the Snapshot system.

> Additionally, it would help to understand what this SimpleState implentation is lacking compared to default implentations. If you look at the source code behind the implementation of the class returned by mutableStateOf(), it clearly has many more features in addition to the barebones implementation of MutableState I wrote above. So what exactly are the consequences of losing these advanced features of the default MutableState implementation?

The default implementation of MutableState (`SnapshotMutableStateImpl`) correctly triggers recompositions because it uses the Snapshot system. A snapshot, as its name suggests, contains a reference to the values of state objects a point in time. Snapshots are always immutable though: a snapshot can be mutated. And after it is mutated, it can be applied to another snapshot.

The snapshot system exists independently of Compose, and the library can even be used directly without compose.

Snapshots can be nested, can be thread local, and there are features related to the invalidation and merging of snapshots. The system sometimes resembles the merging of git commits.

A snapshot can register listeners. Compose registers write listeners using the snapshot system on an appropriate snapshot.

There is a global snapshot that is the "root" of all other snapshots. Any changes are designed to get propagated back to the global snapshot as long as there are no conflicts. The global snapshot behaves in a special way and is coordinated with Compose so that it sends out notifications everywhere in your app before a frame is drawn in order to determine which `Composable` functions need to be redrawn.

**Does the answer to this question in any way depend on the platform? Is there any difference between desktop and android, for example?**

As far as I can see, no. In Desktop, `mutableStateOf` (an `expect` fun) returns an instance of `SnapshotMutableStateImpl`. But `SnapshotMutableStateImpl` is defined in the `common` source set, so it should be compatible with any platform. It looks like Android's `actual` for  `mutableStateOf` might return a different class, but I think it is pretty safe to assume that their behavior is consistent.

I always mentioned in my question a few classes, and I can provide now a brief summary of what each does:

**SnapshotMutationPolicy**

Tells the Snapshot system about how to mutate a state in merge conflicts and whether or not to consider mutations actual changes. By default, equality is determined by structurally `==` and there is no merging.

**StateObject**

An interface to mark something that uses the Snapshot system to keep track of changes. `MutableState` implements this. Other examples are `SnapshotStateList` and `SnapshotDerivedState`.

**SnapshotMutableState**

Probably means a `MutableState` based on the snapshot system.

I think all `MutableState` implementations are likely `SnapshotMutableState`. The docs for this interface say:

> In general for correctness: Anything that is mutable, that is read
> during composition or written  * to during composition, should be a
> [SnapshotMutableState].

**StateRecord**

The value of a state at a particular snapshot. So, one `MutableState` created by the user could under the hood have a collection of StateRecord instances with various values at different times. It is a more internal class, I think the main thing to know is that its just a part of how the Snapshot system works internally.

**StateStateRecord**

`StateRecord` is abstract and is likely used for various data types such as collections, primitives, and objects. `StateStateRecord` is just the implementation used by `SnapshotMutableStateImpl`.

Also, it is important to note that the Snapshot system doesn't only provide a system for observing writes. **It also can observe reads**. This is essential for Compose, as it is how Compose knows exactly where it needs to register a listener.

So at this point we now understand that my implementations of `MutableState` above simply did not deliver on the promises made by the interface. It is basically a stub; it does not comply with expected behavior of the interface.

Reflecting on my original needs, I now have much more thorough understanding and should be able to find a proper solution to my issue of merging my BindableProperty class with MutableState. At a bare minimum, I may do the following:

```kotlin
class BindablePropertyState<T> private constructor(
    private val property: BindableProperty<T>
) : MutableState<T> {

    constructor(initialValue: T) : this(BindableProperty(initialValue))

    private val mutableState = mutableStateOf(property.value)

    init {
        property.onChange {
            mutableState.value = it
        }
    }

    override var value: T
        get() = mutableState.value
        @Synchronized
        set(value) {
            property.value = value
        }

    override fun component1(): T {
        return value
    }

    override fun component2(): (T) -> Unit {
        return {
            value = it
        }
    }

    fun bind(other: BindableProperty<T>) = property.bind(other)

}
```

This implementation is not perfect or ready to use in an actual project, and is just for the purpose of answering this question. Here are the important bits:

1. It uses the provided `mutableStateOf` under the hood. This allows me to avoid worrying about any of the low-level aspects of the snapshot system for now. While it is technically possible to develop a more intricate solution that incorporates low-level Snapshot system features, it is likely more efficient and easy to simply wrap around an existing implementation.
2. Reads must be delegated directly to the MutableState instance. This will ensure that read listeners are properly notified by the snapshot system during Composable execution.
3. Writes can be delegated to either the `BindableProperty` or the `MutableState`, but in any case both must be updated.
4. I use my `BindableProperty.onChange` method to synchronize the two objects. Because in this implementation I only allow writes to the property directly, it is ok that synchronization is unidirectional.
5. I expose the `bind` method of `property` her just as an example for how this allows my MutableState to have additional functinality.
6. Most importantly, I must stay aware that Compose needs to be able to track both reads and writes. So I must be careful, or develop a more intricate solution, to prevent missed read events. Missed read events will cause issues where recompositon will not always occur. For example, here is an easy mistake that could be made:

```kotlin
class VeryBadBindablePropertyState<T> private constructor(
    private val property: BindableProperty<T>
) : MutableState<T> {

    // otherwise same as above...
    
    fun isAnInteger() = property.value is Int

}
```

Here `isAnInteger` is just a very random method I thought of, though I can't think of any particular reason why it would be useful. It is just designed to demostrate a potential pitfall: If this function were called in a `@Composable`, the Composable would not correctly subscribe to this state since there was no direct read on the MutableState.

There are likely a variety of solutions that would be more stable than the above and help ensure pitfalls like that don't occur. But for the purpose of this question, I hope it is sufficient.

Comment: This is an awsome summary! However, after several reads I still don't get it how the magic works ;-[ JetBrains didn't do a good job with this system. The piece that I'm missing is the `BindableProperty`. Is this your own class or jetpack's? I wasn't able to find it anywhere. I guess I'll need to read Zach's blog a couple of times too. Or rather study it. I wish this was explained by JetBrain in their Jetpack's docs :-\

Comment: BindableProperty is mine. Sorry for the confusion about that.

Comment: Isn't Google behind this system? Since it originated with Android?